Mark specific candle based on opening sum digit
The day's opening number is 48786.
To reduce this to a single digit, add all the digits together:
4 + 8 + 7 + 8 + 6 = 33
3 + 3 = 6
So, I want to mark the 6th candle in intraday 5 min time frame. This can be labeled on top of the candle, or the high and low of the 6th candle can be marked with a horizonal ray - line.
logic is if high is broken of 6th number candle i will go long and low broken i will go short
I have tried doing convert number till single digit, but unable to plot lable and horizontal ray
// Function to round off a number
round_off(num) =>
    math.round(num)

// Function to sum the digits of a number
sum_digits(num) =>
    sum = 0
    temp_num = num
    while temp_num > 0
        sum := sum + (temp_num % 10)
        temp_num := math.floor(temp_num / 10)
    sum

// Function to reduce to a single digit
reduce_to_single_digit(num) =>
    temp = num
    while temp >= 10
        temp := sum_digits(temp)
    temp

// Get the opening price of the day
day_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)

// Round off the opening price
rounded_open = math.floor(day_open)

// Reduce the rounded opening price to a single digit
single_digit_sum = reduce_to_single_digit(rounded_open)

// Plot the result as a label on the chart
onedigit= label.new(    x =start915,    y = Upper_ProfitBooking_Level,    text = str.tostring(rounded_open)+"=" + str.tostring(single_digit_sum)+"",    style = label.style_label_down,    color = color.blue,    textcolor = color.white,xloc=xloc.bar_time)
label.delete(onedigit[1])




Here is a way to do it.
I keep track of the daily open price, daily open bar index, and calculate your POI.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_get_sum(p_num) =>
    num = p_num
    int sum = 0

    while (num != 0)
        sum := int(sum + num % 10)
        num := num / 10
    
    sum

is_new_day = timeframe.change("D")

bgcolor(is_new_day ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)

var float open_price = na
var int open_idx = na
var int digit_idx = na

if (is_new_day)
    open_price := int(open)
    open_idx := bar_index

    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(open_price), textcolor=color.white)

    int sum_digit = f_get_sum(open_price)

    while (sum_digit >= 10)
        sum_digit := f_get_sum(sum_digit)

    digit_idx := sum_digit

if (bar_index == (open_idx + digit_idx))
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(digit_idx), textcolor=color.white)



consider
daily_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)

consider
daily_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)
instead of
open_price := int(open)
open price is different.

opening price is different and candle opening is different on Trading view.
consider daily_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)
i made above changes but not giving desire result. need ur expert help.

Could you please tell me a ticker and timeframe where the opening prices are different with those two methods?

consider INDIA - NSE
NSE : banknifty
NSE: nifty
TF will be  5 min to count candle
but consider daily_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)
there always difference in open in 5 min candle and "D" candle

Well, when I look at the Daily chart, I see that the open price in my example matches with the open price on the daily timeframe. Regardless, the method is there, just use whatever input number you want to use.

daily_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open)
i pass above variable but still result the same.
following is chart where daily opening = 22568 = 5
and 5 min TF opening = 22572 = 18=9
https://www.tradingview.com/x/k4Wv6Twe/
