Pine Script - Sum of Digits Logic
Trying to Achieve Logic 435 --> 12 ---> 3
f_add(_number) =>
    var float sum = _number
    while sum > 9
        sum := sum % 10 + sum / 10
    sum == 0 and _number > 0 ? 9 : sum

I tried multiple OPTIONS
// Function to calculate digital root (sum of digits until single digit)
sum_of_digits(n) =>
    digit_sum = n
    while (digit_sum >= 10)
        temp_sum = 0
        temp_n = digit_sum
        while (temp_n > 0)
            temp_sum := temp_sum + (temp_n % 10)
            temp_n := math.floor(temp_n / 10)
        digit_sum := temp_sum
    digit_sum


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78548732/mark-specific-candle-based-on-opening-sum-digit

this worked for me . Thank
